# Can I use replace pinax-theme-bootstrap with any other bootstrap theme?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, pinax

I'm just starting out with pinax "account" starter project, and it comes bundled by default with the pinax-theme-bootstrap.

I was wondering if I could just drop-in replace that theme with some other "bootstrap theme" like from this website: [Bootstrap Starter Template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/).

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I'm also looking to do the same.

Comment: sorry been a long time since that project :( dont remember

Comment: It's ok :) Thanks!